Extract container template for storing a different type
Given a container of a certain type as input, is it possible to "extract" the container template and instantiate it for a different type? For example:
void f ( auto& x ) {
  getContainerTemplate(x)<int> a (10); // getContainerTemplate() 
  // is some magic function.
}

The effect of f() should be the following depending on the type of x:
void f ( std::vector<double>& x ) {
  std::vector<int> a(10);
}

or
void f ( parlay::sequence<double>& x ) { // parlay::sequence is
  // another container template storing elements contiguously.
  parlay::sequence<int> a(10);
}


A bit of a problem is the fact that std::vector<double> is actually std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>>. It's reasonably easy to generically turn std::vector<double, std::allocator<double>> into std::vector<int, std::allocator<double>>, but that of course then fails to compile. It's not immediately obvious to me how to turn it into std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>> instead, without hard-coding specific knowledge of details of std::vector

If you are willing to drop any additional template parameters beyond the first (if any), letting them get default values, then something like this would do it.

Post that as an answer @IgorTandetnik.  I was trying to come up with a similar solution by mine wasn't nearly so clean.

@Igor Tandetnik -- you can use allocator_traits to rebind the new allocator

@Gene Yes, but you would need to hard-code the fact that the second parameter is in fact an allocator, thereby losing generality.

Yes, it is possible. Using a "template template parameter" (see What are some uses of template template parameters?) instead of auto will allow f() to deduce a template type, which you can then instantiate with your own parameters, eg:
template< template<typename, typename...> class Container, typename T >
void f ( Container<T>& x ) {
  Container<int> a(10);
  ...
}

Online Demo

What's a structured approach to becoming good at template meta programming?

I can't answer that, as I'm self-taught. All I can say is study other people's code and practice.

Something along these lines, perhaps:
template <typename T, typename C>
struct ContainerTypeReplacer;

template <typename T, template <typename...> class C, typename... Args>
struct ContainerTypeReplacer<T, C<Args...>> {
    using type = C<T>;
};

template <typename T, typename C>
typename ContainerTypeReplacer<T, C>::type getContainerTemplate(const C&);

Usage:
void f (auto& x) {
  // if x is of type e.g. std::vector<double>,
  // then a is std::vector<int>
  decltype(getContainerTemplate<int>(x)) a(10);
}

Demo

This is trickier than anyone else here is admitting to get perfect.
A simple template template parameter works for 80% of cases, but doesn't in the remaining ones.  As an example, if you want to do it to maps, it won't work because your comparitor may not match.
What you might want to consider is making your containers into monoids, in a Haskell sense.  These monoids publish how to do certain operations on them.  In C++, you'd publish these operations via traits classes; we can attempt to make it work using generic templates, then improve it for specific sub-types.
The easiest way is to write an fmap customization point.  fmap takes a monoid and a function, and creates a new monoid with the contents of the monoid mapped by the function.
On a container, this does roughly what you want.
Supporting basic sequence containers is easy; you can then extend it to support associative containers.  This can go much, much further; you can support smart pointers, optionals, io monoids (representing "computation to do after a user provides input"), futures, etc.

Since c++20 you have concepts, which allows you to operate in same template-function with different types. It could help to operate more safety with different types. For example check std::convertible_to<T>, std::same_as<T> and std::is_floating_point_v<T>

How is this relevant in any way to the question?

@cigien is it possible to "extract" the container template and instantiate it for a different type? - My answer contains more safety variant of "extraction" some type/types from a teamplate.
